# If on click or query string in URL

Tags: jquery

I want to run a function if a specific button is clicked or if a specific query string is in the current URL.

This is my current function:

```
$('#layout-toggle-01').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('layout-active').parents('#events-cal').attr('class', 'events-3-col');
    $('#layout-toggle-02, #layout-toggle-03').removeClass('layout-active');
    $('#events-cont-02, #events-cont-03').hide();
    $('#events-cont-01').fadeIn();
    // Run 4:3 image height function
    fourThreeHeightFn();
  });
```

Could I add a `if(window.location.href.indexOf("?view=columns") >= 0)` condition to this function, or do I need a separate function?

Comment: Sure you can... why not?

Comment: @KobyDouek Okay, more specifically, I'm looking for the syntax to doing so where the function runs if either condtion is met.

Comment: So you want the function to run only if (window.loca....) ?

Comment: @KobyDouek No, if the button is clicked or if that URL query string matches. However, sometimes, both will be true, and I guess I'd only want the function to run once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do a variety of things if either a) there is a correct query string or b) an element is clicked. I would start by defining a function that is the things you want to do. So something like:

```
var doStuff = function () {
    $('#layout-toggle-01').addClass('layout-active').parents('#events-cal').attr('class', 'events-3-col');
    $('#layout-toggle-02, #layout-toggle-03').removeClass('layout-active');
    $('#events-cont-02, #events-cont-03').hide();
    $('#events-cont-01').fadeIn();
    // Run 4:3 image height function
    fourThreeHeightFn();
}
```

Then add the calls to that function based on your requirements. So you get something like:

```
$(function () {
    if (window.location.search.indexOf('columns') > 0) {
        doStuff();
    }

    $('#layout-toggle-01').on('click', function() {
        doStuff();
    });
});
```

Since it looks like you're building something to switch layouts, you could refactor your `doStuff` function to use the value of a parameter passed to it to alter the needed classes rather than coding in the specific id values.

Comment: This is cleaner than what I had in mind and makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

But this might run 2 times..

```
 $('#layout-toggle-01').on('click', function() {
     func($(this));
      });

    if(window.location.href.indexOf("?view=columns") >= 0){
     func($('#layout-toggle-01'));
    }

    function func(e){
       e.addClass('layout-active').parents('#events-cal').attr('class', 'events-3-col');
        $('#layout-toggle-02, #layout-toggle-03').removeClass('layout-active');
        $('#events-cont-02, #events-cont-03').hide();
        $('#events-cont-01').fadeIn();
        // Run 4:3 image height function
        fourThreeHeightFn();
        }
```